# ASP.NET : sending a soap request in a HTTP post request to a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice that exposes a function called ADD(int a, int b)

and i am trying to send a request to it without adding a wsdl/reference and then calling the function, In other words, i want to explicitly send a request to the webservice address.

so if i send a POST request  with a well-formatted-soap XML envelope as the message, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable HttpGet and/or HttpPost in your web.config, you can do what you are asking.

[Enable ASP.NET ASMX web service for HTTP POST / GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests)

Comment: oh, +1 for the help :), will be back after testing :)

Comment: Works like a charm ( actually when i tested i forgot to enable them, so it didn't work at 1st, then i remembered to do it and it worked! , which definitely proves your answer :) )