# Calling ASP.NET web service function via GET method with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, service

I'm trying to call web service function via GET method using jQuery, but having a problem. This is a web service code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://something.com/samples")]
[ScriptService]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class TestWebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public string Test2()
    {
        string result = null;

    try
        {
            result = "{'result':'success', 'datetime':'" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "'";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "Something wrong happened";
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

That's the way I call the function:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost/testwebsite/TestWebService.asmx/Test2",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             alert(xhr.responseText);
         },
         success: function (msg) {
             alert('Call was successful!');
         }
     });
```

Method is called successfully, but result string gets covered by XML tags, like this:

```
<string>
{'result':'success', 'datetime':'4/26/2010 12:11:18 PM'
</string>
```

And I get an error because of this (error handler is called). Does anybody know what can be done about this?

Comment: Where's your '}' on the end of the returned JSON string?

Comment: Do you mean json string covered by XML tags? I think I did something wrong when I copied it from the browser window, it should be there, of course.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't see it in the web service code either.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288850/how-to-return-json-from-a-2-0-asmx-web-service

Answer (score 9):

[Enable ASP.NET ASMX web service for HTTP POST / GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string Test2()
{
   [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Rule for json:
   You can only access data from the **same domain**!
2. The only exception is when using **[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)** (which is quite complicated to implement since there is no jsonp serializer in the .NET framework).
   If your are using a **standard web service** (and **not WCF**) you can find guidance howto implement this **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ASPNET_JSONP.aspx)**.

Comment: For now it should be enough for me to access data within the same domain. But even if I open URL like  this 
http://localhost/testwebsite/TestWebService.asmx/Test2
in browser on my local machine, I see XML rendered. The only thing I need now is to get rid of XML

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this to your ajax options:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Your overall request should look like this to get json back instead of XML:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost/testwebsite/TestWebService.asmx/Test2",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8".
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     },
     success: function (msg) {
         alert('Call was successful!');
     }
 });
```

[ScottGu has a full breakdown on what's required here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx), but it looks like the missing `contentType` in your case (that one drove me nuts for a while too).

Comment: Changing contentType didn't take any effect

Comment: @the_V - What error is it alerting?  also just for kicks, do you get the same behavior with POST?

Comment: POST works fine, but I want to get it working with GET. About error: xhr.responseText is following - <string xmlns="http://something.com/samples">{'result':'success', 'datetime':'27.04.2010 0:57:30'</string>

Comment: @the_V - Try changing `[ScriptMethod]` to `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` on `Test2`, see what your response is.

Comment: Response is the same, string gets covered with XML stuff

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the ResponseFormat on your methods.  See http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494 to see how they did it for JSON.  It probably just defaults to XML.

Comment: I've tried to add following attribute to method definition:

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString=false)]

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate the method with the [ScriptMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx):

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://something.com/samples")]
[ScriptService]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class TestWebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod]
  public string Test2()
  {
    [...]
  }
}
```

This will ensure that the method returns JSON by default (the default value of `ResponseFormat` is `Json`).

Comment: [ScriptMethod] attribute doesn't take any effect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `WebInvokeAttribute`, it has members that define Request & Response formats where you can set to `WebMessageFormat.Json`.
Something like:
`[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ServiceName", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            Method = "POST")]`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use http handler instead of
   web service.
2. You can parse xml response with
   javascript on the client.