# Post data into database via ajax. displays 501 internal error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

i am trying to post data from my asp.net webform into database. i have this in my asp.net service (shoppingcart_service.asmx)

```
 [WebMethod] // 
        public void RegisterSubscriber(string Email)
        {
            new OnlineShopTableAdapters.NewsletterSubscribersTableAdapter().Insert(Email, DateTime.Now);
     //database code


        }
```

this is my html

```
  <input type="button" onclick="saveData()" id="btnSave" value="Subscribe"  >
```

this is my ajax code, which i put in a file called apps.js and linked to my page

//updated !
    function saveData() {

```
 function saveData() {

    var SubscriberEmail = $("#Email").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber",
        data: '{"Email":"' + SubscriberEmail + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {

        }

    });

}
```

but the value doesn't get posted to my database consider the error i got in chrome's console, after clicking the subscribe button

[image: error-snapshot]

Comment: you could try to put a breakpoint in the ASP.Net application to confirm if the request is going where you want

Comment: Your` dataType & data` you can change to `json` & `data : {email : email}`

Comment: Try to change: [url: location.pathname + "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber"] TO  [url: "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber"]   WITHOUT location.pathname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done same thing in one of my projects and it works well..the only difference I can see is that my webmethods return `string/bool` values and also the webservice class has `ScriptService` attribute.

See below:

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class ajaxpost : WebService
 {
     [WebMethod]
     public string Callback(string txbFirstname)
     {
     }
 }
```

and the script side is:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/ajaxpost.asmx/Callback",
        data: '{"txbFirstname":"' + txbFirstname + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {

        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: didnt work bro, wot could i not be getting right. it still showed me internal error :500. but when ever i run the webservice it works

Comment: check your path as @sameh said remove the location.pathname.

Comment: I created a project do you want me to send it to you?

Comment: that will be kind @Zaki enginebox2012@gmail.com. Thanks

Comment: I have uploaded it to github...https://github.com/samimw/AjaxASMX I have sent it to your email too!

Comment: thanks @Zaki, but i just figured it out thou. what i did wrong was the way i asigned the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is ASMX, it doesn't allow POST on Web Methods.
Here's an answer to a similar question [Enable ASP.NET ASMX web service for HTTP POST / GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests) Give it a try.

Comment: @ronmmik, didn't work. i just tried it. i even moved the method to my code behind. didnt still work

Comment: Does the web method get executed at all? Can you put a break point in it?

Comment: the web method is working fine. i tested it by requesting it on the browser

Comment: If you requested in the browser, then it was a GET and not a POST. You will need to use Fiddler (or another tool) to simulate a POST. Can you not run your jquery and watch the break point? Also, I noticed that your datatype: 'jsondata' I'm not sure if that's correct. According to Jquery doc (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it should be json or jsonp

Comment: when i changed to GEt this is what i saw in the cosolehttp://localhost/candc/shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber?{%22Email%22:%22ttttttttttttttttttttttt%22}

Comment: and when i clicked on that, it opened another browser tab with the error Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/RegisterSubscriber'.

Comment: as per Jai's comment  the data is wrong it should be data: {Email: Email} . I would also suggest changing the JavaScript variable name to something else (i.e SubscriberEmail) to prevent confusion. So it should be data: {Email : SubscriberEmail }

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
url: location.pathname + "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber"
```

TO

```
url: "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber"
```

WITHOUT location.pathname

Comment: YEAH JUST DID THAT, STILL DIDNT HELP

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, i finally found the answer, it lied in the way i feed the webmethod parameter below is the code that worked.

```
 function saveData2() {
    var SubscriberEmail = $("#Email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber",
        data: "email=" + SubscriberEmail, // the data in form-encoded format, ie as it would appear on a querystring
        //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", // if you are using form encoding, this is default so you don't need to supply it
        dataType: "text", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
        success: function (data) {
            $("#searchresultsA").html(data); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
        }
    });
    }
```

i didnt need to use curly braces in the data line