# How to make a HTTP request using c# to asmx web-method which is returning Context.Response.Write?

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a web method in asmx web services and it is returning pure JSON using **Context.Resopnse.Write**.

Now the above line will write json data to the connection pipeline of the request but how to accept the response from c# function which is acting as a client to the web-service.

**Here is my web-service method:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetAllEmployeesFromEmpInPureJSON()
{
    SqlConnection vConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
    vConn.Open();
    String vQuery = "Select * from Employee";
    SqlDataAdapter vAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(vQuery, vConn);
    DataSet vDs = new DataSet();
    vAdap.Fill(vDs, "Employee");
    vConn.Close();
    DataTable vDt = vDs.Tables[0];
    Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vDt));
}
```

**Here is the client function:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lab25WebServiceSoapClient obj = new Lab25WebServiceSoapClient();
    DataTable vDt = new DataTable();

    //String jsonstring = obj.GetAllEmployeesFromEmpInPureJSON();
    //vDt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring) as DataTable;
    GridView1.DataSource = vDt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Here the below two lines don't work because it is a void type return method and below code will work when I am returning string instead of using context.

```
String jsonstring = obj.GetAllEmployeesFromEmpInPureJSON();
vDt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring) as DataTable;
```

**I think there should be something like:**

```
String jsonstring =  Context.Request(obj.GetAllEmployeesFromEmpInPureJSON())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consume this service using HttpClient like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync("<domain>/Lab25WebService.asmx/GetAllEmployeesFromEmpInPureJSON").Result;
```

To get this to work I had to do a couple of things:

- Add protocols to the web.config of the service as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests) describes.
- Replace the existing ScriptMethod attribute with `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]`

Comment: What is your point of doing this. If I want this way then I would just create a function in client itself and call it. Here what is the use of having web-method. I want client to receive as the ajax call receives data or like HttpClient which will create a connection and can pass and receive data.

Comment: An handler will send data to user when it requested. For example an handler can be called like " image.src = "ImageHandler.ashx?id=1" and it will return context.response. I am thinking there should be some way similar to this

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question. I've changed my answer to include an example of how HttpClient could be used to get the Json from your service