# Enable GET request using Web Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using aspx page.
Is there a way to enable GET request using WebMethod?
This is the link I am trying to reach in debug, but it doesn't stops on break point:

> http://localhost:32725/Rest/DialerWebMethods.aspx/dial

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Dial() {

        return "test";                        

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable ASP.NET ASMX web service for HTTP POST / GET requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests)

Comment: Unfortunately,  It doesn't solved my problem .

Comment: IS the problem that it doesn't work or is the problem that you can't set breakpoints? The title suggests that it just doesn't work but your talk of breakpoints suggests otherwise...

Comment: Is it working? Are you getting the returned value, even if it doesn't stop on the break point?

Comment: The problem is when I run in debug and trying to reach this url(that I quoted), it dosent reach to this function 'dial' in code, and doesn't return the value.

Comment: Are you able to call other WebMethod in the class ?